# control pan tilt and zoom camera using python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, camera, python-multithreading, logitech

I've been tried control PTZ camera pro 2, but the video stream and pan tilt still can't work together. Maybe someone can solve this issue. Feedback and suggestion are welcome.

This is complete code using python language for control PTZ Camera.
https://github.com/deviraanggi/Logitech-PTZ-Pro-2-Control

python3

```
from ctypes import *
import time
import ctypes
import clr
import os
import sys
import cv2
import PTZ
import clr
clr.AddReference('cobabikindll')
import PTZ
from PTZ import PTZDevicess, PTZType
device = PTZDevicess.GetDevice("PTZ Pro 2", PTZType.Absolute);
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    #device.Move(-1, 1)
    device.MoveInternal(30,35)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The link given no longer exists. Do you know if the code has been moved to somewhere that the link could be updated with? (Question on behalf of @awet-haileslassie)